# Helm Fail In Cloud Build

Tags: continuous-integration, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, google-cloud-build

I'm using `alpine/helm:3.0.0` in the following Google Cloud Build step

```
- id: 'update helm app'
  name: 'alpine/helm:3.0.0'
  args: ['upgrade', 'staging', './iprocure-chart/']
  env:
  - CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=us-central1-a
  - CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=iprocure-cluster
```

The problem is when i run this using `cloud-build-local` i get the following error and the pipeline ends with a fail

```
Starting Step #4 - "update helm app"
Step #4 - "update helm app": Already have image (with digest): alpine/helm:3.0.0
Step #4 - "update helm app": Error: UPGRADE FAILED: query: failed to query with labels: Get http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets?labelSelector=name%3Dstaging%2Cowner%3Dhelm%2Cstatus%3Ddeployed: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

Comment: Has your build resulted successful using another Cloud Builder? It seems that the upgrade command is not reaching the container. Remember that cloud-build-local runs on your machine. Have you followed the configuration steps listed here:

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-debug-locally#before_you_begin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the configuration has not been set or passed.
To configure checkout = https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-debug-locally#before_you_begin

and in your build step add a evn like this :

- id: 'update helm app'
  name: 'alpine/helm:3.0.0'
  args: ['upgrade', 'staging', './iprocure-chart/']
  env:

  - CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=us-central1-a
  - CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=iprocure-cluster
  - KUBECONFIG=/workspace/.kube/config

If this does't work try passing the config with --kubeconfig flag in your helm command.Like this :
--kubeconfig=/workspace/.kube/config..